# Can't find Element with Selenium

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Im trying to scrap the price of a flight from the Google Flights website using Selenium but said element does not show up anywhere, not even when scraping the whole page. Ive read that it might be due to it being in a different frame, but how would I know in which frame it is.

Here is the website: https://www.google.es/flights?lite=0#flt=/m/0h3tv./m/05qtj.2018-12-14;c:EUR;e:1;a:FR;sd:1;t:f;tt:o

The price I'm looking for is: 32 €

And here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

d = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/davidgarciaballester/Desktop/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

url='https://www.google.es/flights?lite=0#flt=/m/0h3tv./m/05qtj.2018-12-14;c:EUR;e:1;a:FR;sd:1;t:f;tt:o'
d.get(url)



precios = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').findAll('jsl',{'jstcache':'9322'})


print(precios)

d.quit();
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: jstcache changed value to 9322

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: No data, the list is empty.

Comment: Are you sure it's precios = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser').findAll('jsl',{'jstcache':'9383'})??

I'm seeing it as 9322

Comment: You're right, the number changed since the last time I saw it. Doesn't matter though, I cant see the number even when scraping the whole page.

Comment: It's highly likely the number is dynamically generated meaning it's not a reliable way to retrieve the element.  You'll need a constant attribute of the element that you can reference back to each time the page load.

Comment: You're right. I tried Qharr's code which is a CSS selector but it doesn't seem to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following CSS selector combination:

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get("https://www.google.es/flights?lite=0#flt=/m/0h3tv./m/05qtj.2018-12-14;c:EUR;e:1;a:FR;sd:1;t:f;tt:o")
item = d.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.flt-subhead1.gws-flights-results__price.gws-flights-results__cheapest-price span + jsl')")
print(item.text)
d.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! As Idlehands pointed out the number probably changes dinamically so a CSS seelctor is probably best in this case. I've tried out your code but it doesn't seem to be retreiving any data.

Comment: I'm not matching on number. I am matching on position. But why it is not retrieving anything is odd.

Comment: Ok its working now. Or rather it was working the whole time, I had a syntax error. Just realized now. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear :-)

Comment: Awesome approach @QHarr.

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



d = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

url='https://www.google.es/flights?lite=0#flt=/m/0h3tv./m/05qtj.2018-12-14;c:EUR;e:1;a:FR;sd:1;t:f;tt:o'
d.get(url)

page = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')

precios = page.findAll('jsl',{'jstcache':'9322'})

print(precios)

d.quit();
```

worked for me:

```
print (precios[0].text)
```

gave me `€32`

Comment: Not working for me still. Copied your exact code and changed the webdriver path, still no result. Other pages work fine so its not an issue with my computer.

Comment: ah ok. Good call on the sleep/wait time. Glad it’s working now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured out what was going on. I wasn't giving the driver enough time to load the page. Fixed this by stalling for a few seconds after loading the page.

Working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



d = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/David/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')

url='https://www.google.es/flights?lite=0#flt=/m/0h3tv./m/05qtj.2018-12-14;c:EUR;e:1;a:FR;sd:1;t:f;tt:o'
d.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

page = soup(d.page_source, 'html.parser')

precios = page.findAll('jsl',{'jstcache':'9322'})

print(precios)

d.quit()
```

**EDIT 1:** As Idlehands pointed out the jstcache number is probably dynamic and changes over time, so this aproach was not well thought. Instead I'm now using the following CSS selector combination QHarr suggested. Working code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

whitelist = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789')

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

d = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/David/Desktop/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)

url='https://www.google.es/flights?lite=0#flt=/m/0h3tv./m/05qtj.2018-12-14;c:EUR;e:1;a:FR;sd:1;t:f;tt:o'
d.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

precio = d.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.flt-subhead1.gws-flights-results__price.gws-flights-results__cheapest-price span + jsl')").text
precio = ''.join(filter(whitelist.__contains__, precio))

print(precio)

d.quit()
```

Comment: time.sleep() is an awful solution... use a WebDriverWait

Comment: Agree that `sleep()` is a bad idea, unless you just need a quick and dirty solution for a script that won't be running long term and stability and speed isn't a concern.

Comment: Ok im looking into WebDriverWait. Thank you for your advice pals!

Comment: Sorry for asking so much but I've been trying out the WebDriverWait but I cant seem to get it working. Ive read several tutorials and tried for several hours, and the closest i think I've got is: 

WebDriverWait(d, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".gws-flights-results__cheapest-price gws-flights-results__price"))) 

Could someone point out what I'm missing on?